# How to fix negative in sum of two textboxes involving time

Tags: excel, vba

I have a userform where there are two textboxes where a user inputs downtime and it puts it in a list box, now in this same userform I have another disabled textbox that displays the total sum of all the numbers in minutes of those two times, the code works well, the issue lies when for example: user inputs 2300 in the "txtTStart" textbox and 0010 in the "txtTEnd" it brings a -1370 number. My question is how can I get the correct sum for this method.

```
Private Sub cmdNext_Click()

Dim x As Integer
Dim totaldt As Double
Dim r As Long
Dim tdt As Double
Dim tdtt As Double

If Trim(Me.txtTStart.Value) = "" Then
    Me.txtTStart.SetFocus
    MsgBox "Please Enter Time Start"
    Exit Sub
End If
If Trim(Me.txtTEnd.Value) = "" Then
    Me.txtTEnd.SetFocus
    MsgBox "Please Enter Time End"
    Exit Sub
End If
If Trim(Me.cmbCode.Value) = "" Then
    Me.cmbCode.SetFocus
    MsgBox "Please Enter Downtime Code"
    Exit Sub
End If
If Trim(Me.txtDesc.Value) = "" Then
    Me.txtDesc.SetFocus
    MsgBox "Please Enter Downtime Description"
    Exit Sub
End If
If Trim(Me.txtDesc.Value) = "INVALID DOWNTIME CODE" Then
    Me.txtDesc.SetFocus
    MsgBox "Please Insert Valid Downtime Code"
    Exit Sub
End If

    tdt = Format((CDate(txtTEnd.Value) - CDate(txtTStart.Value)) * 1440)

tdtt = Round(tdt)

x = lstDes.ListCount

With lstDes
         .AddItem
         .List(x, 0) = txtTStart.Value
         .List(x, 1) = txtTEnd.Value
         .List(x, 2) = tdtt
         .List(x, 3) = cmbCode.Value
         .List(x, 4) = txtDesc.Value

End With

totaldt = 0
With lstDes
    For r = 0 To .ListCount - 1
        totaldt = totaldt + .List(r, 2)
    Next r
End With

txtDT.Value = totaldt


Me.txtTStart.Value = ""
Me.txtTEnd.Value = ""
'Me.txtTot.Value = ""
Me.cmbCode.Value = ""
Me.txtDesc.Value = ""

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

please add this line:`if tdt<0 then tdt=tdt+1440` to your code after the line:

```
tdt = Format((CDate(txtTEnd.Value) - CDate(txtTStart.Value)) * 1440)
```

Comment: THANK YOU! You saved me from a world of headaches.

Comment: :):):):):):):):)